# Why do we need to mark a Swift class `public` or `open` to make it accessible in an Objective-C framework project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

As title.

But based on Apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c), it says:

> Methods and properties that are marked with the internal modifier and
>   declared within a class that inherits from an Objective-C class are
>   accessible to the Objective-C runtime.

It says `internal` should work.

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: in your quote there is nowhere said that you have to make it public or open, you don't have to do that, they can stay internal to access from obj-c

Answer (score 2):

Classes will be accessible to runtime, but not to programmer.
You will need class headers to operate with them.
Xcode will just generate public Objective-C headers for you, if you mark them as public.